# Controle de tabs do navegador com javascript

Tags: javascript, aba

Boa noite. em meu site tenho uma lista de links que abrem com um `target='_new'`

O que estou tentando fazer em javascript ou jquery é que quando algum destes links for clicado ele vai abrir a outra aba do navegador mas o focus vai ter que continuar na mesma janela que lista os links.

Isto é possível?

pesquisei sobre popunder mas não resolveu.
também tentei usar esta função

```
window.opener.focus();
```

Comment: Acho que vai contra o proposto pela world wide web esse tipo de atitude, de proibir o usuário de acessar outras abas.

Comment: relacionada: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/107017/como-impedir-que-o-usu%C3%A1rio-feche-uma-p%C3%A1gina-sem-enviar-o-formul%C3%A1rio-por%C3%A9m-sem-u

Comment: entendi. nao tem como ter controle a menos q eu crie a windows ne?